# remove the blank rows after i removed xml elements?

Tags: php, xml, dom, simpledom

i removed some elements from a xml file with simpledom.

the code:

```
$this->xmlDocument->removeNodes("//entity[name='mac']");
```

here is the initial file:

```
<entity id="1000070">
    <name>apple</name>
    <type>category</type>
    <entities>
        <entity id="7002870">
            <name>mac</name>
            <type>category</type>
        </entity>
        <entity id="7024080">
            <name>iphone</name>
            <type>category</type>
        </entity>
        <entity id="7024080">
            <name>ipad</name>
            <type>category</type>
        </entity>
    </entities>
</entity>
```

the file afterwards:

```
<entity id="1000070">
    <name>apple</name>
    <type>category</type>
    <entities>




        <entity id="7024080">
            <name>iphone</name>
            <type>category</type>
        </entity>
        <entity id="7024080">
            <name>ipad</name>
            <type>category</type>
        </entity>
    </entities>
</entity>
```

i wonder how i could also remove the blank lines that are left after i ran the removal code?

thanks!

Comment: You can remove the blanks , but you will probably not end up with nicely indented (prettified) XML. You will probably end up with `<entities><entitiy id="xxx">` on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the whitespace text nodes with XPath.

If the nodes you want to remove are `//entity[name='mac']` then the whitespace text node before it would be

```
//text()[normalize-space(.) = ''][following-sibling::entity[position()=1][name='mac']]
```

And then, you can remove both nodesets by using the `|` operator and your command becomes:

```
$this->xmlDocument->removeNodes(
    "//entity[name='mac'] | //text()[normalize-space(.) = ''][following-sibling::entity[position()=1][name='mac']]"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you'd like to remove **ALL** these blank spaces for your output, there's a simple way below:

```
$this->xmlDocument->removeNodes(
    "//entity[name='mac'] | //text()[normalize-space(.) = '']"
);
```